# Real Time Optical Flow

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv, opticalflow

I'm using optical flow as a real time obstacle detection and avoidance system for the visually impaired. I'm developing the application in c# and using Emgu Cv for image processing. I use the Lucas and Kanade method and I'm pretty satisfied with the speed of the algorithm. I am using monocular vision thus making it hard for me to compute the depth accurately to each of the features being tracked and to alert the user accordingly. I plan on using an ultrasonic sensor to help with the obstacle detection due to the fact that depth computation is hard with monocular camera. Any suggestions on how I could get an accurate estimation of depth using the camera alone?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out this paper: [A Robust Visual Odometry and Precipice Detection System Using Consumer-grade Monocular Vision](http://free.download4.org/A-Robust-Visual-Odometry-and-Precipice-Detection-System-Using-download-w2838.pdf). They usea nice trick for detecting as well obstacles as holes in the field of view.

Answer (score 2):

Hate to give such a generic answer, but you'd be best off starting with a standard text on structure-from-motion to get an overview of techniques. A good one is Richard Szeliski's recent book [available online](http://szeliski.org/Book/) (Chapter 7), and its references. After that, for your application you may want to look at recent work in SLAM - Oxford's [Active Vision group](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~lav/) have published some great work and [Andrew Davison's group](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~ajd/) too.

Answer (score 1):

more a comment on RobAu's answer below,
'structure from motion' might give better search results, than '3d from video'

Comment: Hi, I've looked into structure from motion. As far as my research has gone, SFM is consumes a lot of resources and would not be too favorable for real time processing.

Answer (score 0):

Depth from one care will only work if you have movement of the camera. You could look into some **3d from video** approaches. It is a very hard problem, especially when the objects in the field of view of the camera are moving as well.